# SSIS and SQL Agent job impersonation

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent

I currently have a new SSIS machine. SSIS is used to automate maintenance task such as backups and restores of other servers on the network. We have over 600 servers in our line of business and each server has their own NAS location for backups. I have created a proxy account that access to all servers and the shares on all NAS devices where all the backups reside.

That's my setup. My issue is that the agent on my SSIS machine needs to have access to read and write to the NAS locations for all the servers in order for the job to successfully do the backup/restore request.

My question is: can I impersonate the SQL agent as the account that already has access to all the servers and locations? This way I don't have to grant my SSIS machine access to 600 servers.

Comment: Careful implementing a single point of failure for all maintenance jobs that run against your 600 SQL Servers. If anything goes wrong, that is a large impact area. I prefer to keep my maintenance job local to the instance they run against to reduce points of failure.

Comment: To confirm - you created a credentialed user in SQL Server and **then** added them as a _proxy_ to SQL Server agent job step(s) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy?view=sql-server-ver15  The question is then, can I use the proxy in SQL Agent Jobs?

Comment: Brendan you are right and I agree. This backup and restore process is unique because its for the SSISDB and this backup and restore process needs to create keys and decrypt them at the server destination. This process will be used on certain servers of the 600 but I dont know what servers will be source or destination until users request. Then at that point security will need to be done between SSIS server and both servers in the transaction.

Comment: billinkc there are jobs running with Proxy account already that's not an issue. This job is using the proxy that works fine with other jobs. Issue is that the agent running SSIS server does not have access to the share location and then that security has to be manually created.

Comment: TSQL BACKUP and RESTORE always use the SQL Server Service Account, not the Agent Service account or any Agent proxy for access to the backup location.

Comment: Thank you David, so in order for the job to access the backup folder the SQL Service Account running job must have at least read access to the folder to read bak files. If this account can not be impersonated then access must be granted to said  Service account is what your saying.